# Performance of 4 Times an Add Operation vs. 2 Times a Multiplication Operation Added Together in C

Tags: c, performance

In ANSI C, which of the following is faster, and why? Or doesn't it make a difference because it will be compiled to the same?

```
int main(void) {
    double width = 4.5678;
    double height = 6.7890;

    double perimeter = width + width + height + height;

    return 0;
}
```

Or the following:

```
int main(void) {
    double width = 4.5678;
    double height = 6.7890;

    double perimeter = width * 2 + height * 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with `(width + height) * 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will figure that out, and use whatever is fastest. Possibly even compute `perimeter` at compile time.

You should concentrate on writing the most readable code. That helps both humans and the compiler to understand your intentions.

Comment: but floating-point math isn't associative like normal math, so many times the compiler can't optimize those out

Comment: You have to use `-ffast-math` if you want gcc to do optimizations that require changing the order of FP operations.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see what a compiler will do with something, don't give it compile-time-constant data.  Also, don't do it in `main`, because gcc disables some optimizations for "cold" functions, and `main` is automatically marked that way.

I tried it on [godbolt](https://goo.gl/S7IP7O) to see if different compiler versions made a difference.

```
double f1(double width, double height) {
    return width + width + height + height;
    // compiles to ((width+width) + height) + height
    // 3 instructions, but can't happen in parallel.  latency=12c(Skylake), 9c(Haswell)
    // with -march=haswell (implying -mfma),
    // compiles to fma(2.0*width + height) + height, with 2.0 as a memory operand from rodata.
}

double f2(double width, double height) {
    return width * 2 + height * 2;
    // compiles to (width+width) + (height+height)
    // 3 instructions, with the first two independent.  Latency=8c(Skylake), 7c(Haswell)
    // with -mfma: compiles to weight=+weight;  fma(2.0*height + weight)
}

double f3(double width, double height) {
    return (height + width) * 2;
    // compiles to 2 instructions: tmp=w+h. tmp+=tmp
    // latency=8(Skylake), 6(Haswell)
}

double f4(double width, double height) {
    return (width + height) * 2;
    // compiles to 3 instructions, including a move because gcc (even 5.2) is dumb and generates the temporary in the wrong register.
    // clang is fine and does the same as for f3()
}
```

With `-ffast-math`, they all generate 2 instructions: `tmp=(width+height); tmp+=tmp;`.  gcc 4.9.2, 5.1, and 5.2 all generate an extra `mov` in many of the sequences, even with -ffast-math.  They don't have this problem with 3-operand AVX versions, of course, but AVX is too new to use without checking that it's supported.  (Even Silvermont doesn't support it.)